# how to use properties values in web.xml

Tags: java, xml, properties

Hi everyone it has been a long time I was looking for the solution but even if I found some explanation it wasn't that clear.

I want to replace an URL in the web.xml with its key defined in `URL.properties` here is the URL I want to replace in web.xml

```
<param-name>chainConfig</param-name>
<param-value>org/apache/struts/tiles/chain-config.xml</param-value>
```

In my properties file I have :

```
URL.chainconfig=org/apache/struts/tiles/chain-config.xml
```

So I want to use in my web.xml something like `${URL.chainconfig}` instead of the full URL.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One way is you can set the value to environment variable and read it using ${vaiableName} inside your web.xml

In Linux type sudo vim /etc/profile
    export URL.chainconfig=org/apache/struts/tiles/chain-config.xml

Save and exit. Now it will get replaced in web.xml during run-time.

Comment: thanks for ure quick answer i appreciate a lot,only am workin under windows.i heard about a class which implements ServletContextListener that may help i use it but still cannot recognize my key in the web.xml.

Comment: Ali In windows also you can set environment variables, you can try that also

Comment: if my way is totally wrong is there any way to configure the environnement variables in windows

Comment: one last thing krishna.do we need to set a environnement variables for every machine where the programme will run if its so,its not the solution

Comment: bad news am not allowed to modify the environnement variables.

Comment: am in internship and wedont have this kind of rights

Comment: ya you need to set it either manually or you need to write a listener which will read and set it.

Comment: yeah taht what i did is my class listner is correct?if yes what else should i add?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the very same problem without environment variables,  creating a new InitListener that reads the desired properties, as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12099590/3202887