# Set the context-param in web.xml from properties/XML file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How to set the value of context-param in web.xml file from a external properties/XML file when my java web application gets started.

Comment: I do not think that's possible.

Comment: see if you want something that has already been done in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099008/how-to-include-values-from-properties-file-into-web-xml

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK web.xml doesn't allow setting context-param from a file, only "static" declaration. That's the spec. You can probably create web.xml dynamically during the build time or something, but the chances are that it's not what you want.

However, you've also tagged "spring"/"spring-mvc" in the question, depending on usage this can open a variety of options for configuration from various sources, but you'll have to be more specific in a question and describe what exactly you want to configure there

Comment: It is possible to do like below by initializing a ContextListener class
<context-param>
    <param-name>myparam</param-name>
    <param-value>${my.param}</param-value>
</context-param>