# Properties file as init-param in web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters, web.xml

I am migrating a Jsp-servlet based Java project that was hosted in websphere to tomcat. Following init-param is in web.xml inside a filter definition. I moved the properties file src folder which is classpath. How to change the following in the web.xml. Can I define properties file as init-param because most of the answers I saw has used context-param to define properties file. I dont think its an option to me as the existing application needs the properties file to be init-param.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>configPath</param-name>
    <param-value>/pws/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/fyp/filterConfig/filter.properties</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I tried

```
<init-param>
      <param-name>configPath</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:filter.properties</param-value>
</init-param>
```

It did not work.Thank you in advance,

Comment: Are you loading it via .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream  ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948992/using-properties-in-web-xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your servlet implementation,you will find something like the following:

1. get the context root path from ServletContext;
2. append the property file path get from init-param;
3. do some file operation

As you asked,you can config the servlet as :

```
    <init-param>
      <param-name>configPath</param-name>
      <param-value>filter.properties</param-value>
   </init-param>
```

then change your code to

1. get the file name from init-param
2. open the stream this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fileName");
3. do some file operation