# Configuring web.xml for resources

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, web.xml

Can I configure my web.xml to look for the resources(like properties file) to a particular position.

Like during the build am not adding any properties file to WEB-INF/classes folder, what I want to achieve is that during runtime it should get the required properties file from specified position defined in web.xml!!

How to achieve it??

Comment: have you try `<import resource="path/file with extension"/>` ?

Comment: this thing works in spring ryt??
Here am not using spring

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to just define a variable in your web.xml naming an environment variable pointing to your properties file?

like: export CFG_LOCATION="/var/local/config/mycfg.properties"

and in web.xml

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>cfg_localtion_variable_name</param-name>
  <param-value>CFG_LOCATION</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: also have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948992/using-properties-in-web-xml

Comment: by the way... putting configuration values inside a compiled-applicaiton is most-time a bad idea except they are static (like localization). to configure your application use the method above, or read your values from database cfg-table by using a datasource with jndi-lookup.

Comment: the thing is, I have to deploy multiple war file in single tomcat, and those war files are using properties file of same name but key-value pair inside properties file may differ... so in order to get it done I have configure it in such a way that if request comes from abc.war(suppose webapp name is abc) then it should go to its respective location and pick those properties file, and I can't change the code...So I have to do like that or any other way is there without changing code?

Comment: Hi i did it in the following way.
I just pointed my variable to a directory instead of a file.
The file name of the properties file is excatly the same as my servlet-context. so for an application registered as "http://localhost:8080/abc/" by properties file is abc.properties in $CFG_LOCATION directory.
If you are using spring check out PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Comment: I am not using spring

Comment: Of course this can also be done using your own class e.g. providing a static instance of your Properties if you are not using spring. ;)